# How to show Product Attributes in Magento 1.9 Frontend?

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, product-tab

How to show Product Attributes in Magento 1.9 Front-end?

Answer (score 2):

You can get attribute on frontend :

```
<?php $_product->getAttributeText('attribute_code'); ?>
```

or

```
<?php $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```